# Formatting text in Crystal Reports

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I need users to be able to enter text in a webform with some basic formatting options and then generate a report showing the formatted text.

The support for HTML is horrible and entering a simple bulletlist doesn't even show properly in the report.

Right now i'm using a textarea with tinyMCE but that's because i don't know what else to use.

Is there a known best-practice for showing formatted text in a Crystal Report?

**Edit**

I just need to show a report with a bunch of text and icons. Users need to be able to save it to PDF. I doesn't even have to be Crystal Reports but it's what i have been using and worked so far. Until i needed to show formatted text.
I wish for another solution that comes with a designer and let's me bind against a DataSet.

Comment: Sorry, I have a bias against Crystal Reports that's probably unfair. It is a good product, but I have to ask - Is using Crystal a requirement? If you want to have HTML formatting, there are so many easier options out there... Even writing your own report in ASP.NET would be easier.

Comment: I don't like CR but for the moment i'm stuck with it until i have a better option. Please read the edit in my question and answer accoordingly.

Comment: there really isn't enough information here to determine what you are trying to achieve. You say "I just need to show a report with a bunch of text and icons" - so show a report with a bunch of text and icons; Crystal is perfectly capable of that. If you can be more specific about what you want to do, that you have been unable to achieve so far, the rest of us will be more able to help you.

Comment: The first lines explain it all. If you have ever tried to show html formatted text in CR you'll now what i mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to convert the HTML to RTF. RTF support in CR is much better than it is for HTML. This way users can still use the tinyMCE editor and even paste Word formatted HTML.

The way i convert the HTML to RTF if using an XSL stylesheet. Basically you load the HTML as an XML document and let the XSL translate it to RTF. This way you also have a lot of freedom over the way your text will appear since you can tweak the XSL.

I used [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/HTML/XHTML2RTF.aspx) to achieve that, the article's attachment includes the .XSL.